# How to write this apple script

Tags: applescript

I want to write an apple script that if it sees a json of a very certain format, it copies to the clipboard all the individual lines with the keys and all the individual values without the keys

For example

```
{
  "stam": "value1",
  "stam1": "value2",
  "stam2": "value3"

}
```

I want the lines to be copied to the clipboard the following way:
I mostly want it to go on my clipboard history, each line on its own

```
"stam": "value1",
value1
"stam1": "value2",
value2
"stam2": "value3",
value3
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Where is it looking for such a thing exactly? On your desktop? In a Pages document? In the clipboard? How is it started? When?

Comment: the data is in my clipboard, I want the apple script to detect this in the clipboard and change the clipboard history accordingly

Comment: Your handling of trailing commas seems inconsistent... one is retained, another is discarded.

Comment: fixed that, i can live with the commas

Answer (score 0):

As there don't seem to be any takers for an **Applescript** version after 2 days, I'll offer a shell method which you are welcome to ignore if it's not for you.

So, if you copy your JSON into your Clipboard and run the following in the Terminal, it should do what you ask:

```
pbpaste | awk -F':' '/:/ {gsub(/ /,""); print; gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

That pastes the Clipboard into `awk` (which is included in every macOS) and tells it to treat the colon (`:`) as the field separator. It then looks for and processes only lines containing colons as follows. It removes all spaces and prints the line. Then it removes all double quotes (`"`) from the second field on the line and prints the result on a new line.

So, if you make a script called `$HOME/go` containing the following, it will write the result back onto your Clipboard:

```
#!/bin/bash
pbpaste | awk -F':' '/:/{gsub(/ /,"");print; gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' | pbcopy
```

You can then make it executable (only necessary one time) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Then you can execute it from **Applescript** with:

```
do shell script "/Users/YOU/go"
```

---

Or, if you insist on Applescript you can do something ugly like this:

```
set lns to paragraphs of (the clipboard as text)

set res to ""
repeat with ln in lns
    if (ln contains ":") then
       set res to (res & ln & "\n") as string
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
       set fields to every text item of ln
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
       set val to (item 2 of fields)
       set res to (res & val & "\n") as string
    end if
end repeat
display dialog res
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this does almost what i need
i guess i wasnt clear enough in my request. I wanted each line to be copied separately, so that i would have 6 clipboard history items, and not one. One for each line